# Block all direct IP requests but allow domain requests

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

What is the best linux option to block all direct IP requests to the public eth interface IP but at the same time allow certain fqdn(domain-based) requests?

Example:

The server's public IP is 166.137.1.1 and www.mywebsite.com DNS points to that server and IP. Here are some scenarios:

1. request to 166.137.1.1 - BLOCK (on all ports)
2. request to www.mywebsite.com - ALLOW (only ports 80 and 443)
3. request to www.maliciouswebsite.com which points without my knowledge to my server's IP of 166.137.1.1  - BLOCK (on all ports)

Example 3 gives a malicious user the ability to, for example, spoof webserver's environment variables (CGI scope) such as HTTP_HOST

Comment: IP packets only have IP addresses. DNS looks up the IP address of a host before building an IP packet with the IP addresses. There is nothing in IP that has anything to do with DNS names, which are an application-layer concept. IP does not use names, only numbers.

Comment: ok, i was hoping something like IPTABLES can do a lookup. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

By the time a packet gets to your machine, you have absolutely no information as to whether the initiating user/software/process used the IP address or DNS name.

Answer (score 3):

It's the HTTP 1.1 protocol that allows to decide what to do based on the hostname given in the `Host:` header, so you can't do this on TCP packet level at the firewall. Still, you could get almost similar results:

1. At the firewall `DROP` every packet except those to ports `80` and `443`.
2. At the web server

   - create a default catch-all virtual host that responds with error `404 Not Found` or shows some simple "hostname not configured here" page. Or `301` to your canonical hostname; whatever you wish.
   - create another virtual host only serving content for the correct `Host:` header.